# Semigroup with data type that contains function

Tags: haskell

I have following data type and `Semigroup` instance of it:

```
newtype Combine a b = 
  Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }

instance (Semigroup b) 
  => Semigroup (Combine a b) where 
  Combine {unCombine=f} <> Combine {unCombine=g} = Combine (f <> g)
```

What does `Combine (f <> g)` mean? I pass the function `f` and `g` to the binary operator `<>` what is the output of it?

To figure out how it works, I try to play a bit in prelude:

```
Prelude> let f = Combine $ \n -> Sum (n + 1)
Prelude> let g = Combine $ \n -> Sum (n - 1)
Prelude> unCombine (f <> g) $ 0
Sum {getSum = 0}
```

For me it looks like a function composition `f` after `g`, but am I not sure, how does exactly work. Could someone tell me, how does it work?

Another example(maybe it does not make sense):

```
*Exercises Data.Semigroup> data Zoo a b = Zoo (a -> b)
*Exercises Data.Semigroup> x = Zoo (+23)
*Exercises Data.Semigroup> :t x
x :: Num b => Zoo b b
```

How to use `x`?

Comment: `unCombine (f <> g) $ 0` applies `f` with `0` and `g` with `0` and then applies the inferred `Semigroup` operation with the result of both functions. For `unCombine (f <> g) $ 0` the codomains of `f`/`g` are of type `Sum Num` and the corresponding binary operation is just `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f <> g` is calling the library instance for functions:

```
instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) where
   f <> g = \x -> f x <> g x
```

So, it is defined pointwise.

Perhaps using generalized newtype deriving would have been better here, since `Combine` has exactly the same instance. One might even wonder if `Combine` is needed at all.

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail about `library instance for functions`?

Comment: The `Data.Semigroup` contains exactly the [instance above](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.20/base-4.9.1.0/Data-Semigroup.html). So, when you use `<>` between functions, that instance gets called.